# TFS 2008 Build Script

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build-script

In TFS 2008, I am trying to modify a build script (TFSBuild.proj).  I get the following warning:

```
The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element 'TeamProject' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.
```

Which is correct, The element PropertyGroup does indeed have a child called TeamProject.

I’m making an assumption that this is caused because of the following line:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="DesktopBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
```

The Xml Namespace doesn’t appear to exist as far as I can tell, although it looks like a standard one.  Please can anyone tell me if this is a standard XML namespace, how or where I can view its contents and whether the warning that I am seeing may be caused by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question can be [found at this link](http://sstjean.blogspot.com/2007/04/visual-studio-warning-element-in.html), and to summarise:

> You can safely ignore this warning.  So does MSBuild validate your
>   project files against the schema?  Yes it does, but I wasn't sure just
>   how it was accomplished, so I fired off an email to Buck Hodges.  He
>   was nice enough to pass it by an as-yet-unnamed-dev on the MSBuild
>   team.  The dev stated that
>
> "...MSBuild does try to validate against the schema.  However, the
>   validation is done at runtime by our code rather than loading the
>   [project] file using a validate reader with the xsd (mainly for perf
>   reasons).  MSBuild should fail any projects which don't adhere to the
>   schema."

Answer (score 2):

You're editing A SCRIPT file in Visual Studio editor, it will always try to find missing elements in the namespaces. I have the same "infos" (not errors) when I'm using custom tasks or custom libraries. The best way to solve it is to get used to it:).
Remember these are only warnings from the editor.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I realise that what I am seeing it not an error, but I was curious as to where the namespace that I mentioned came from, where / how it's viewable and whether it caused the message.  Before I can get used to something, I have to understand it.